# My screen doesn't turn off when VLC is open

Tags: unity, screen, vlc

I recently installed 12.04, but I had the same problem in 11.10. When I watch a video, VLC suppresses the monitor being turned off. In older (pre-Unity) Ubuntu versions, this would only be in effect while the video was playing. Now VLC is disabling the turning off of the monitor regardless of if it is playing or not.

Is there a way to fix this? Or a less quirky shell? Or a video player that doesn't exhibit this behaviour?

Comment: Only difference is you're unchecking the box. ^

Comment: @EvanCarroll It seems like doing that would allow the screensaver to interrupt VLC regardless of what it's doing. What if they want to stop the screensaver when video is played but not otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

## 1.

check for,

```
Tools => Preferences => Show All => Video => Disable screensaver
```

[image]

if you want to enable screen saver uncheck it.

```
Tools => Preferences => Show All => Advanced => Inhibit the power management daemon during playback
```

[image]
uncheck this to make monitor turn of while playing in vlc.

## 2.

try this script for respective options

```
#!/bin/bash

xset -dpms #do not allow turn off
xset s off #do not allow screen saver

xset dpms #Allow turn off if not work then try -dpms
xset s on #Allow screen saver
exit
```

Comment: I already had those settings, but thanks dawg.

Comment: @user973810 what do you mean ? you have both the settings checked or unchecked? BTW try script given it always works.

Comment: Those 2 settings were already checked, and the script didn't fix a thing.

Comment: @user973810 uncheck both settings. Close VLC. then play video. I have already tested.

Comment: Do you have any new ideas? This still isn't working. It's been almost five years now.